# How can i splite large num of sqlite database into different number of files in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

I have a 2 gbs of SQLite database. I try to CRUD operation, at that time my query execution takes too much time. I want to 2 gbs of database split into 1-1 gb of database bunch, so that my CRUD execution process fast.

Comment: what does [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) show?

Comment: @thor Can we ask how you created a db with 2 gigs of data ? And what is a long time in terms of min or sec please. One suggestion that will be a fair amount of coding is two db tables that hold the same data ie tableONE all records from A to M and tableTWO records from N to Z from here you will need new code to save the data to the correct table and new code to know which table to search you get the idea and we did this as a poof of concept and found it to be a real pain working out the design. We scrapped the concept

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about how to optimize your DB and queries.